# Changing form upon input

Tags: javascript, css, html

There will be two inputs to the form, the "From:" and "To:" locations. Upon the user entering these values, using the Google Maps API v3 I will calculate the distance and create a price, however I want the form to shift into a new (larger) form and display the results (i.e. price, tolls, sales tax). How would I go about creating a dynamic form that changes upon user input?

Comment: You could change the class of the form on button click and use larger area for the new class.

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't have a transition. Is there a way to make it a smooth transition?

Comment: I think something like this .classSmall {width: 100px; transition: width 5s;} .classLarge {width:200px;} and add .classLarge on button click

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/Lhebc8u8/

Add a class on button click and add the transition in css/

```
$("#btn").click(function(){ $("div").addClass("classLarge"); });

.classSmall 
{
    width: 100px; 
    transition: width 2s; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
} 

.classLarge {width:200px;}
```